# JavaScript: mousebutton down propagating down to image and can't make it stop

Tags: javascript, firefox, drag-and-drop

I have a project to create and drag a semi transparent div over an image, the purpose is to allow visually highlighting parts of the image.

Note I am using jquery for most of this.

This is mostly working, the div drags around just fine. However, the I also want the ability to click on the image itself to create such a div and then drag it around.

So my procedure is: on mousebutton down event on image, create the div and begin dragging.
However firefox is interpreting this mousebutton down and doing some browser gui stuff (chrome works fine.) That despite the fact that the event handler returns false to stop propagation.

I have a jsfiddle to illustrate (note it is cut down to be as simple as possible, so obviously some stuff needs usability improvement.)

In it you see a yellow box on top of an image. mouse down and drag on this box and it drags around perfectly.

However, mouse down outside the yellow box and it will create a green div similarly, the idea being that you mouse down and drag, and get the same effect on the new green div. However, the browser interferes with the event. Try it and see.

I have been banging my head against a brick wall to get the browser to stop seeing the event to no avail. So your help would be appreciated.

The code is pretty straightforward:

```
beginDrag(e)  // event handler for mouse down
createBeginDrag(e) // Create a new div then call begin drag on that div
moveDrag(e) // event handler for mouse move to perform the drag
moveEnd(e)  // event handler for mouseup and mouseleave to end the drag
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fraserorr/ty82Q/embedded/result/

Code for the jsfiddle is as follows (note this needs to include jquery):

```js
var dragX, dragY;
var lastItemNum = 1;
var lastItem = "#yellow";

function beginDrag(e) {
    dragX = e.clientX; dragY= e.clientY;
    $("#outer").on('mousemove', moveDrag);
    $("#outer").on('mouseup', endDrag);
    $("#outer").on("mouseleave", endDrag);
    $('#log').append('MD[' + e.clientX + ',' + e.clientY + '] -> [' + dragX + ',' + dragY + ']   ');
    return false;
}

function createBeginDrag(e) {
    lastItemNum++;
    var html = "<div class='green'";
    html += "id='green" + lastItemNum + "' "; 
    html += "style=";
    html += "'left:"+(e.clientX-50)+"px;";
    html += " top: "+(e.clientY-50)+"px;'";
    html += "></div>";
    $("#outer").append(html);
    lastItem = '#green' + lastItemNum;
    beginDrag(e);
}

function moveDrag(e) {
    var deltaX = e.clientX - dragX;
    var deltaY = e.clientY - dragY;
    var offset = $(lastItem).offset();
    dragX = e.clientX;
    dragY = e.clientY;
    offset.top += deltaY;
    offset.left += deltaX;
    $(lastItem).offset(offset);
    $('#log').append('MM[' + e.clientX + ',' + e.clientY + '] -> [' + dragX + ',' + dragY + ']   ');
    return false;
}

function endDrag(e) {
    moveDrag(e);
    $("#outer").off('mousemove', moveDrag);
    $("#outer").off('mouseup', endDrag);
    $("#outer").off("mouseleave", endDrag);
    $('#log').append('ME[' + e.clientX + ',' + e.clientY + '] -> [' + dragX + ',' + dragY + ']   ');
    return false;
}    

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#yellow").on('mousedown', beginDrag);
    $("#outer").on('mousedown', createBeginDrag);
});
```

```css
img { position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; }
#yellow { position: absolute;
    top: 100px; left: 300px;
    width:100px; height:100px;
    background-color: yellow; opacity: 0.3;
    float: left;
}
.green { position: absolute;
    top: 100px; left: 300px;
    width:100px; height:100px;
    background-color: green; opacity: 0.3;
    float: left;
}
#log { font-size: small; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='outer'>
    <img src='http://blogs.warwick.ac.uk/images/mhillebrandt/2007/02/21/venice_high_water.jpg?maxWidth=800&maxHeight=600'/>
    <div id='yellow'></div>
</div>
<div id='log'></div>
```

Comment: post the code here, not just the function calls you are using.

Comment: The code is in the jsfiddle, it seems easier to see it there than posting it all in this question.

Comment: Links die, and users shouldn't have to go to an external site to see the code.

Comment: OK, thanks, I will post the code as you recommend...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your click event you need to check if the the target of the click is the image, if it is not simply return

```
function createBeginDrag(e) {
    if(e.target.nodeName!="IMG" && e.target.tagName!="IMG") return true;
```

Note if you want the green divs to be draggable by clicking and dragging on them change

```
$("#yellow").on('mousedown',beginDrag);
```

to

```
$(document).on("mousedown","#yellow,.green",beginDrag);
```

and change your mouseDrag to

```
function moveDrag(e) {
    var deltaX = e.clientX - dragX;
    var deltaY = e.clientY - dragY;
    var target = $(e.target).hasClass("green")? $(e.target) : $(lastItem);
    var offset = target.offset();
    dragX = e.clientX;
    dragY = e.clientY;
    offset.top += deltaY;
    offset.left += deltaX;
    target.offset(offset);
    $('#log').append('MM[' + e.clientX + ',' + e.clientY + '] -> [' + dragX + ',' + dragY + ']   ');
    return false;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ty82Q/57/)

Comment: Thanks for your help Patrick, but this solution is still a little off. If you go onto the image and mousedown then mouse move around, firefox shows a little no-go sign and the div doesn't follow the cursor. if you mouse up the drag catches up and mousedown again gets it dragging, but the initial drag is kind of messed up. Do you see what I am saying?